# transform rotation in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I try to write rotation preloader:
http://codepen.io/davidchase/pen/qkKpx
The problem is that is not working in IE11.
there in code some

```
 -webkit-transform: rotate ...
 -moz-transform
```

I try to use -ms- but it still not working, how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer does not use a vendor prefix for transforms, except very briefly in (iirc) IE9 developer preview where it used `-ms-`.

Just do it without prefixes. This isn't 2006 anymore.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNXQvY

Comment: but how about safari on windows? how to add backward compatibility?

Comment: My personal opinion: screw backward compatibility. If people can't be arsed to update, then I can't be arsed to program for their special snowflake selves.